# Using a Panel Regression to Explain Aggregate Effects/Interpreting the "size" of panel regression coefficients

Tags: panel-data, variance-decomposition

Suppose I've estimated a two way fixed effects regression using unit level panel data:
$$
y_{it} = \beta_1x_{it} +\beta_2x_{it}H_{it} + \beta_3H_{it} + a_i + \gamma_{t}+\epsilon_{it}
$$
with $(a_i, \gamma_{t})$ being the usual two way fixed effects and $y_{it}$ being some unit level outcome e.g. individual wages. How can I relate $H_t$ to overall changes in $y_t$. I know that in each of the T cross-section regression(s) of:

$$
t=1,...T;\;
y_{it} = \delta_0 + \delta_1x_{it} +\epsilon_{it}
$$

that $\delta_{T} \neq \delta_{T-1} \neq \delta_{T-2} $ and so on. Is there a way to evaluate the contribution of the average trend in $H_{t}$ over the whole period to the changing sizes of $\delta$. I have in mind a very specific application where say, $\delta$ is a the impact of having a college degree versus no college degree and $H_{it}$ might be any continuous unit-specific policy variable i.e. local AFDC levels, job openings, pollution. The overall goal is to decompose $\delta_t$ at the aggregate level into a component explained by changes in $H_t$ and a component that isn't and estimate the overall contribution of $H_t$ to $\delta_t$ using individual level panel data.

I've heard that this is related to the "missing intercept" problem for difference-in-difference designs but haven't been able to find much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to ask for clarification with a comment, so I'm going to incorporate my uncertainty about the question into the answer. First, it is not clear to me whether $x$ ("college degree") is time-variant in this model, which it would have to be in order to be included in a two-way fixed-effects model that eliminates all between-unit variation. The part of the question related to regressions of cross-sections of $x$ at each time period suggests you are interested in a between-unit relationship (individuals with or without college degree). On the other hand, the $H$ variable is clearly time-variant, and it seems like you are interested in the effects of its changes (AKA within-unit variation). If I'm wrong and $x$ is actually time-variant, and you want to include it in a fixed-effects model, then what you'd be measuring is the effect of *getting* a college degree at different values of $H$ that are deviations from the mean of $H$ for that individual over the whole panel. It would not be equivalent to saying it is the effect of *having* a college degree, as that, to me, has a between-unit logic.

If I'm right that $x$ is time-invariant for individuals during the panel and $H$ is modeling change specifically (within-unit variation during the panel), then you need a model that can include both between-effects ($x$) and within-effects ($H$) (definitely not a standard fixed-effects model), and I have a potential solution.

As you likely know, fixed effects models more often use unit demeaning rather than including unit/individual dummies ($a_i$). Demeaning accomplishes the exact same thing as unit dummy variables, and both methods drop time-invariant variables, because $x_{it}$ (an individual's deviation from their panel mean) is always zero for time-invariant variables with unit fixed-effects.

An alternative is the within-between fixed effects model. In this model $y$ is not demeaned, nor is there a $a_i$. Instead, for each time-variant variable, there is a unit-demeaned version (within) and a second variable that is the average value of the variable for each unit/individual during the period (between). In this model, you can additionally include any time-invariant variable (like $x$), and it can be interacted with demeaned $H$.

The effect of $x$ is not truly decomposed (to me that sounds like mediation and not moderation/interaction), but something similar is achieved. The interpretation of the coefficient for $x$ outside of the interaction (the equivalent of $\beta_1$ in your equation) is the effect of having a college degree while values for $H$ (within-unit variable) are at their mean values for individuals during the panel (due to the individual demeaning process). I'm not sure if this satisfies a "decomposed" effect, but you are able to identify the between-individual effect of having a college degree or not, while each individual is at their individual, panel-average value of $H$.

This is all quite complicated to do in terms of transformations, but there is a package for R called [panelr](https://panelr.jacob-long.com/articles/wbm.html) that takes care of everything. This page also explains the within-between model in much more elegant terms than I have here.